# I have sold the Golden Claw, can I get it back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I apparently have sold the Golden Claw, I am not entirely sure where and seem to have lost it. This has stopped me from finishing the quest.  I am using the xbox 360 edition

Comment: Instead of editing the [tag:xbox-360] tag in and out all day, how about you guys read [the meta about platform tags](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless)? Specifically, the paragraph that says "**Platform Tags are Widely Misused**".

Comment: I think that was a conflict in editing lol I somehow got an edit through when it was pending

Comment: There should have been down votes because the claw is a quest item. It can't be dropped.

Answer (score 3):

all you got to do is after you sell it to the guy in the riverwood trade store, just walk out wait about a day (or until morning) go back inside and it should be on the counter in front of him. if you sold it to somone else you have to usually buy it back or it might be gone some traders don't hold the items you sell them. So check every trader you have sold things to.

Answer (score 0):

If you could sell it then probably your quest was completed. The Golden Claw is just for the Golden Claw quest. If you're really stuck and are playing on PC, try this command in the console to finish the quest: `setstage MS13 100`

Comment: using Xbox the OP said

Comment: Are You Sure Quest is Not Over?

Comment: @Marriott81 whether OP is playing on PC or not is irrelevant - this question is for everybody with a similar problem (although noting that the console command is a PC-only solution would be appropriate).

Comment: @kotekzot thats what I was referring too